# Subspace test for space of $2\times2$ matrices, determine basis for $W:=\{M \in M_{2,2}(\mathbb R) | M^T = -M\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm sorry I don't know where to start on this question

Let $M_{2,2}(\mathbb R)$ denote the vector space of 2 by 2 matrices.

Define: $W:=\{M \in M_{2,2}(\mathbb R) | M^T = -M\}$ and $U := \{M \in M_{2,2}(\mathbb R) | M^T = M\}$

where $M^T$ denotes the transpose of $M$. Use the subspace test to show that $W$ is a subspace of $M_{2,2} (\mathbb R)$. Find a basis for $W$. Determine U∩W. Find a basis $B$, for $U$. Extend $B$ to a basis $M_{2,2}(\mathbb R)$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Constraint $M^T=-M$ is equivalent, by taking $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ to $$\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-a&-b\\-c&-d\end{pmatrix}$$ Therefore $ a = -a $, etc.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

First note that for $w\in W$, $w$ is in the form 
$\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\-a&0\end{bmatrix}$. Do you see why the diagonal has to be $0$?

Next, look at $u \in U$, where $u$ is in the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&d\end{bmatrix}$. Can you prove to yourself that both of these forms represent elements of $W,U$ respectively?

Now, what do you know about the subspace test? Take any $w_1,w_2\in W$ in the form above and prove to yourself that $W$ is a subspace of $M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Given the representation of elements in $W$, how many elements do you need to form a basis? Can you figure out what this basis looks like? Use similar ideas for $U$.

Lastly, what do elements in $W$ and $U$ have in common? Use that to solve for their intersection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still don't quite understand. Subspace test involves scalar and addition but what would be the requirements you have to fulfil to pass the subspace test. Wouldn't you need two basis?